# Way(s) of browsing the filesystem that are more flexible

Tags: filesystem

I have two related questions, both probably (but not necessarily preferentially) accepting the same answer :

1. When browsing or exploring the filesystem in a GUI, I want to be able to right click on the empty space between the files, choose a menu item and say 'open terminal in this folder,' *optionally as root*
2. Do the converse when using the terminal, *optionally as root*

I use Universe with kubuntu but have Debian Lenny running with gnome installed separately, so anything on kde or gnome would work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Terminal to Nautilus

For the terminal side of things, I would just add this to my `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias browse="xdg-open ."
alias browse-root="gksudo xdg-open ."
```

### Nautilus to Terminal

The nautilus-open-terminal extension that others have mentioned is great for most use, but it does not provide a way to open a root shell. The easiest way for you to get this functionality is to save a script like the following as `~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts/Open in Terminal (Root)`:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI
gnome-terminal -x sudo -s
```

A fun variation on this would be to make a GNOME Terminal profile called "root" with a scary red background color, an initial title of "Root Terminal", and the custom shell command `sudo -s`. You'd then use a Nautilus script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=root
```

Comment: `xdg-open .` and `sudo xdg-open .` are be better because they work on KDE as well as GNOME.

Comment: That's usually the better way to go, but currently `sudo xdg-open .` fails due to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/517984).

Answer (score 8):

You can use [xdg-open](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man1/xdg-open.1.html) to **open files and directories from the command line**. I have an alias of `xopen` to make the typing a little easier. Put this in your `~/.bashrc` to do that, and to have a root file browser using sudo:

```
alias xopen="xdg-open"
alias xopen-root="sudo xdg-open"
```

It will open the file in the application that would be used if you double-clicked on it. For example, if you named a text file, it would open in gedit. And if you pass it a directory, it will open the file browser. So if I am in my home directory I can do

```
$ xopen Documents
$ xopen .
```

and the file browser (nautilus for me) will open that directory. Also note that xdg-open will return immediately - the new program is launched as it's own process and you can type in your next command.

To **open a terminal from the nautilus file browser**, you should install the `nautilus-open-terminal` package. Then you can right click on a folder, or in the blank space below the files, and open a terminal with the path set to that directory. Not sure how to make it a root terminal though - I always just use sudo myself.

Comment: You should consider adding to your answer then aendruk tip on xopen-sudo.

Answer (score 3):

There's a nautilus script handily packaged in the Ubuntu repositories to do this for you.  [Click here to install](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/nautilus-open-terminal) or run the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal
```

You may have to restart gnome/nautilus for it to work.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have Ubuntu-tweak installed, you can also just tick the box for nautilus extensions.

Not sure if it's compatible with Lenny, right enough!  :-)

[image]